# CakePhp FormHelper - Date field issue

Tags: date, cakephp, formhelper

In the "view" of my "register" action , I tried to create a date field for the date of birth.

```
echo $this->Form->input("Member.dateofbirth", array(
            "label" => "Date of birth",
            "name" => "date_of_birth",
            "id" => "date_of_birth",
            "empty" => true,
);
```

But when I send data with submit button, and make a `debug()`, I see that `$this-> request->data["date_of_birth"]` contains only the year, and does not contain the month and day.

```
debug($this->request->data["date_of_birth"]);
```

Result of debug() :

```
array(
    'date_of_birth' => '1990'
)
```

Comment: Which is the type of the field in the database?

Comment: DATE (It's a MySQL Database)

Comment: Ddid you try using the default field name? I mean, removing the `"name"` option in the FormHelper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that if you set the `name` option in the `FormHelper`, it will only modify the name of the first input (date fields have 3 inputs). That's why you only get the year when you try to read the field with that name.

If you don't really need a different input name, you should stick with the defaults.

So, in this case, removing the `name` option in `FormHelper` will allows you to read the field like `$this->request->data["Member"]["dateofbirth"]`

Comment: It's strange, because it changed the name for the three input. But anyway, you solved my problem, thank you! ;)

Comment: So, you ended up with three inputs with names `"data[Member][date_of_birth][year]"`, `"data[Member][date_of_birth][month]"` and `"data[Member][date_of_birth][day]"`? If it was the case, then you should be reading it like `$this->request->data["Member"]["date_of_birth"]`

Comment: No, they have all the same name "date_of_birth" :D I guess that this was the problem. When I tried to access the three informations using $date_of_birth, only the last one is stored.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. I guess you should not use `id` or `name` options in date fields when using `FormHelper`, because it will generate wrong html. I case you need to change those attributes, you should create 3 different fields.

Comment: Yes you're right. It's just that I don't like those long names. :D
Thanks again for your help ! ;)